# Correlation between principal components and external variables

Tags: python, pca, dimensionality-reduction

Given an input dataframe with `n` features, and `s` samples, where we perform a PCA such that we then represent samples in a 1 Principal Component axis (a simplified case of this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_iris.html)). I am then interested in seeing how correlated is each PC with a given external (sample-associated) variable, either categorical `cat_var` or numerical `num_var`.

Empirically, it would seem to me that this would be a matter of computing the correlation (or regression) between the PC1 projected values of a sample and those of `cat_var` and `num_var`.

```
import numpy as np

pc1 = [-2.3, -1.5, -0.3, ... , 0.3, 1.5]
num_var = [ 12, 15, 8, ... , 3, 4]
cat_var = [ 3, 1, 2, ... , 1, 2] #encoded as integers

my_corr=np.corrcoef(pc1, num_var)
my_corr2=np.corrcoef(pc1, cat_var)
```

Does this make sense? Am I missing anything in here?

Comment: Why do you want this? What is your goal?